# Automatically appending the CRS name in composer?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, print-composer

I'm trying to find a way to automatically append information to a text box in the QGIS print composer.

I've figured out how to call my user name, project name, date and other information, but I'm having difficulty finding a way to append the project CRS name and EPSG code (not just EPSG code). Using `layer_property` function, I can manually set it to evaluate a layer present in my workspace, but I'd like it to automatically grab the projection that map0, 1, 2, 3, etc. is using.

Is there a universal method of automatically evaluating and outputting project CRS in a map composer text box?

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/254034/51507

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not built into QGIS 2.x. This is likely to change with QGIS 3.0 - see https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/3968 which was designed to allow this use case.