# Adding coordinate system to layout in QGIS composer?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, print-composer, qgis-3

I would like to know if there is a way to add a dynamic coordinate system field into a QGIS composer layout.

I can use an expression to add many items such as document name, file path, etc but I can;t seem to figure out how to add the coordinate system?

Comment: If you are using QGIS 3.x now, you may wish to move your green accept checkmark to the QGIS 3.x answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This answer was provided and accepted prior to the release of QGIS 3.0.

**To get the Authority ID (i.e. "*EPSG:4326*"):**

- You can simply use the expression `[% layer_property( 'your_layer_name_or_id', 'crs' ) %]`

**If you want to get the textual description of the CRS (i.e. "*WGS84*"):**

- AFAIK, you must create a custom function. To do this, go to "Insert
  an expression", and type the following function in the Function Editor
  tab.

Code:

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def get_crs(layer_name, feature, parent):
    return QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0].crs().description()
```

- Click on "Load"
- In the Expression tab, type `get_crs( 'your_layer_name' )`

Answer (score 10):

> **Answer for QGIS 3.x:**

**A) For the CRS name of a specific layer use this:**

Add this script to your custom functioneditor:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def get_crs(layer_name, feature, parent):
    return QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0].crs().description()
```

[image]

and then get the crs name in expression editor with

```
get_crs(@layer_name)
```

[image]

Or use the expression `layer_property( @layer_name, 'crs_description')` as suggested by @etrimaille

**B) For the CRS name of your project (for example projection in your print layout) use this:**

Add this script to your custom functioneditor:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def get_projectcrs(project_crs, feature, parent):
    return QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(project_crs).description()
```

[image]

and then get the crs name in expression editor with:

```
 get_projectcrs(@project_crs)
```

[image]

*Of course you can also type in e.g. `'EPSG:4326'` manually or use another function than `@project_crs` which returns an EPSG-code. E.g. `get_projectcrs('EPSG:3006')`*

**Notes:**

Also take a look at https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html for more information about changes in QGIS 3.x

Comment: Thanks @MrXsquared !
I previously tried exactly that code but didn't use the @ when passing the name of the layer.
However, I still can't get this to work. When I add a map in the layout view and insert a label with the aforementioned function, the 'Output Preview' just shows _NULL_ and no information is added in the label.
I checked everything several times, the map has a name (and id) and a CRS but nothing shows up. It shouldn't depend on the specific CRS used, right?

Comment: Of course this will not work in layout view since this refers to a specific layer. I edited my answer and added a function to return the used crs of your **project**. You can use this in your print layout to display the name of the used projection.

Comment: For your answer A, no need to have a python expression. You can do ` layer_property( @layer_name, 'crs_description')`.