# Adding name of used coordinate system using alabel in QGIS Layout?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3, layouts

Is there a way to display the name of the used CRS in the layout?

The expression "project_crs" displays the code of the used CRS but I'd like to use the common name of the reference systems.

This question was asked and answered before as [Adding coordinate system to layout in QGIS composer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254002), however the api the answer used changed with QGIS 3.0 and the solution is not valid anymore.